# How can I pass a variable set by ACF to header.php?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom field with Advanced Custom Fields for my posts. My variable is set product_image, so I can print it with:

```
<?php the_field('product_image'); ?>
```

But I need to print it in my site-header section, within **header.php**, *only for single posts*.

```
<?php if( is_single('post') ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('product_image'); ?>">
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>/logo.png">
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the post id as the 2nd argument on `the_field`.

```
global $post;
the_field('product_image', $post->ID);
```

or

```
the_field('product_image', get_the_ID());
```